# Apache displays "Default Page" when using https://www.example but works for https://example

Tags: apache2, configuration, redirect

I am having trouble with my Apache config and cannot get it to serve up my main webapp when I enter the URL that includes WWW (https://www.example.com) but it works fine when I don't (https://example.com).

I have tried adding the individual lines:

- ServerAlias www.example.com
- ServerAlias *example.com

to all of the VirtualHosts but that made no difference.

From my tests I see the redirects work but I can only access the main site via certain URLs:

- http://www.example.com [image: OK]
- http://example.com [image: OK]
- https://example.com [image: OK]
- https://www.example.com [image: BAD]

I was wondering if someone could help me solve this so I can hit my mainsite from any URL. Also I have to demo this site to a customer very soon and am scrambling for a solution!

Here is my Apache configuration:

**000-default-conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /home/user/project_1/static
    <Directory /home/user/project_1/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

   ServerName example.com

   Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

**default-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Alias /static /var/www/example.com/static

        <Directory /home/user/project_1/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/user/project_1/media
        <Directory /home/user/project_1/media>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ...
        ...

        <Directory /home/user/project_1/mywebapp>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess user python-home=/home/user/project_1/env_mywebapp python-path=/home/user/project_.......

        WSGIProcessGroup mywebapp
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project_1/mywebapp/wsgi.py

        ServerName      example.com

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**le-redirect-example.com.conf** *(Created by let's encrypt certbot)*

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ServerSignature Off

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redirect.error.log
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for your help!

[UPDATE]

Here's the output from running the command "curl -I"

```
root@host1:~# curl -I www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 18:23:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

```
root@host1:~# curl -I example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 18:24:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

```
root@host1:~# curl -I https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 18:25:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzBcrBOvUDUdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; expires=Mon, 15-Apr-2019 18:25:23 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

---

```
root@host1:~# curl -I https://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 18:26:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Jan 2017 02:48:33 GMT
ETag: "1234-12347b43...."
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 11321
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your config:

```
ServerName example.com
```

This matches example.com, but not www.example.com. That's two different names. If you use https (as you do, based on the config), you also need either a certificate with multiple names, wildcard or separate certificates for example.com and www.example.com.

Use `ServerAlias www.example.com` to add an alias to the ServerName. This is also documented in the [excellent apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html), which should be the first stop when something is not working:

> When a request arrives, the server will find the best (most specific) matching  argument based on the IP address and port used by the request. If there is more than one virtual host containing this best-match address and port combination, Apache will further compare the ServerName and ServerAlias directives to the server name present in the request.

Comment: That is correct. However, adding ServerAlias might not solve the problem if DNS records or hosts are also not set properly. example.com and www.example.com must resolve to the same IP.

Comment: @nobody yes, but he says that www.example.com gives the default page. This indicates that DNS is set correctly :)

Comment: You are right. I overlooked that.

Comment: I have tried adding ServerAlias www.example.com to all three conf files directly after the ServerName directive, then restarted Apache service. But still get the "default page" for https ://www. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: What does your Apache log say?

Comment: When I visit the https only URL then I see new entries appended to access.log - however - when I visit the www URL I see entries appended to other_vhosts_access.log

Comment: @Logic1 Did you restart apache after changing the configs?

Comment: I always run "sudo service apache2 restart" after any change.

Comment: Does www.example.com and example.com point to the same IP?

Comment: Just tried pinging the server from a windows shell I get a response from the same IP with both variations.

Comment: That's a bit odd. If you add www.example.com as serveralias for your :80-vhost and run curl -I www.example.com, what output do you get?

Comment: Just updated the original post with the output from running that command.

Comment: And if you add ServerAlias on the ssl-host as well? Also get a ssl cert with example.com and www.example.com ( `certbot -d example.com -d www.example.com` )

Comment: At the moment I think my customer is testing the site (so I am a little hesitant to run anything that I'm not sure I can change back - but I can later on tonight).. But when I run just "certbot" it asks: Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for? (1. example.com -or-  2. www.example.com). Does that help any?